# javascript code to trigger animation works only once

Tags: javascript, css

I have a function that's supposed to make an element blink for 1.5 seconds when a button is clicked but it only works once. If I press it again the blink animation won't be triggered.

The strange thing is that when I add a click breakpoint in dev tools and follow along after clicking the button the blinking effect does happen.

```js
function testFunc(spacerefval) {
  console.log('testFunc was executed!')
  var blinkEl = parent.querySelector('.pin[data-space="' + spacerefval + '"]');
  if (blinkEl.classList.contains('pin--blink')) {
    classie.remove(parent.querySelector('.pin[data-space="' + spacerefval + '"]'), 'pin--blink');
    classie.add(parent.querySelector('.pin[data-space="' + spacerefval + '"]'), 'pin--blink');
  } else {
    classie.add(parent.querySelector('.pin[data-space="' + spacerefval + '"]'), 'pin--blink');
  }
}
```

```css
.pin--blink {
  animation: flicker 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    stroke: #a9234d;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    stroke: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a codepen link so we can know what is going on? In that way, we can help you faster.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and JS in a [mcve]

Comment: @FarbodShabani Much better to post the code here if possible. Stacksnippets work great in most cases

Comment: That is a good idea but I think you need to add the HTML too.
Can you do that please?

Comment: The css animation works, but the JavaScript has multiple errors and design flaws.  The code works only once because it adds the "pin-blink" class.  Yet, the code to toggle the class off again is broken.  What is "classie"?  Why does the code use "parent" rather than "document"?  Why does it use a lengthy if statement rather than a simple [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)?

Comment: @Yogi the answer to most of your questions is that i'm very new to JS. toggle works but when i want to reactivate the animation i have to click twice. is there any way around that?

Comment: @FarbodShabani the html is way too large. i honestly wouldn't know how to extract a useful snippet.